# Trying to find a story about simulated evolution and god

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story many years ago wherein a programmer develops a simulation of evolution.

Eventually, sapient life evolves and tries to communicate with him, their god. So he takes control of a prince in order to teach them English to facilitate better communication. Later on in the simulated civilization's development, he returns claiming to be their god but they don't believe him. He prophesizes some event to happen and leaves. Then he makes the event happen and goes back in where the simulated life begs him to either bring them into his world or kill them.

He doesn't want to kill them and explains that he cannot bring them into his world. Then there's a power surge and the whole world is lost, and the main character wonders about the potential similarities between him and his god.

Comment: so many stories using this theme. i wonder what the first one was? mysterious stranger by twain? sort of island of dr. moreau also.

Comment: I get a strong Greg Egan vibe from this, but the details don't quite fit either "Crystal Nights", or the Lambertians in "Permutation City"

Comment: There was a similar themed story "[Mathematical Revelations](https://escapepod.org/2021/12/16/escape-pod-815-mathematical-revelations/)" by Helen De Cruz on [*Escape Pod*](https://escapepod.org) episode 815 in 2021.

Comment: God Game by Andrew Greeley? https://www.fantasticfiction.com/g/andrew-m-greeley/god-game.htm

Comment: @Lexible Thank you for the link to Escape Pod, didn't know about this site.

Comment: You are most certainly welcome! @RobertF Let us not forget [*Podcastle*](https://podcastle.org) and [*Pseudopod*](https://pseudopod.org) while I am at it.